# How to write socket data to SourceDataLine

Tags: java, android, audio

I'm writing an application which has to get audio from a socket connected device. The connection in question is to an Android device which sends the audio byte per byte over the socket.

Now, my question is - How can I, starting from the first incoming byte, convert this data to sound on my microphone? I am trying to convert the bytes to audio so that I can use it in programs like Skype. I've read quite a few examples about this, but none of them really helped me .

I know this code is crappy , but I'm really stuck. I hope you can help me further:

```
Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

int mc = 0;
int finalMc = -1;

while (mc < (mixerInfo.length - 1)) {
    DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class);

    if ((mixerInfo[mc].getName()).startsWith("Microphone")) {
        finalMc = mc;
        mc = mixerInfo.length + 1;

    }

    mc++;
}

Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[finalMc]);
```